# TexStudio editor Math Highlightng in different environment

Tags: texstudio, breqn

I would like to customize the settings for text highlighting on TexStudio.

I'm working with lot of big and small equations and using the breqn package. Here is some sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[mathpazo]{flexisym}
\usepackage{breqn}
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{dmath}#1\end{dmath}}

\begin{document}
    A small inline equation: $small$\\

    A regular non-inlined equation:
    \begin{equation}
        Regular = \omega \times \delta
    \end{equation}

    A big equation that might need line breaks:
    \begin{dmath}
        Big = \omega \times \delta + bla + bla + bla + bla + bla  + bla + bla + bla + bla  + bla + bla + bla  + bla + bla + bla  
    \end{dmath}

    The way I'd like to deal with this:
    \eq{something = \omega + \delta}    
\end{document}
```

And the result is fine:

[image: The resulting PDF]

However, when working on the text editor of TexStudio, the code looks like this:
[image: Working with TexStudio]

My question: Is there a way to get TeXstudio to understand that the dmath environment is an equation environment so that it does not highlights the math symbols in red but use the formatting used in the equation environment? Would it be possible to do the same with the custum command as well?

Comment: I don't use TeXstudio, but perhaps the documentation can help you: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html

Comment: You need to write your own `.cwl` file I think, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102272/texstudio-how-to-add-custom-highlighting-for-custom-environment

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361283/117534 for a bit more detail on how to write `.cwl`. Reading the documentation on cwl classification format will also be useful

Comment: @Troy yep, that did the trick, nice catch =)