# In TeXstudio some commands on mouseover gives in tooltip "unrecognized command" but compiles correctly. Why?

Tags: amsmath, texstudio, amsart

In TeXstudio some commands on mouseover gives in tooltip "unrecognized command" but compiles correctly. For example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}

\begin{document}

\address{Computer Science Department\\
    University of Winnebago\\
    Winnebago, MN 53714} 

\end{document}
```

Here `\address` on mouseover gives in tooltip "unrecognized command" but compiles correctly.

---

**Screenshot from TeXstudio:**

[image]

---

**Screenshot of compiled pdf:**

[image]

---

**Screenshot of compilation log:**

[image]

---

**Question:** Why in TeXstudio some commands on mouseover gives in tooltip "unrecognized command" but compiles correctly?

Comment: TeXStudio will mark all commands as undefined that are not explicitly listed in one of its list for auto-completing commands. This does not influence the ability to use them in your document - as you notice it compiles just fine.

Comment: If this is bothering you, you can create custom list of commands, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102272/texstudio-how-to-add-custom-highlighting-for-custom-environment for more information

Comment: @samcarter So, it is the error of TeXstudio and not Latex and will not influence the result of compilation, right?

Comment: I would not call it error, but you are right, it won't influence the result.