# Red box around begin{textblock*}

Tags: texstudio, box, textpos

I have installed the package `textpos` which is required to use the `textblock*`  function. Why is it that when I write: `begin{textblock*}` it is around a red box, like if it wasn't a right function. In spite of that, it works and text appears in the document.

[image]

Comment: your editor doesn't know the function, but as long latex knows it this is not a problem.

Comment: Is there any way I can make TeXstudio know it?

Comment: yes, I think texstudio has configurations files somewhere, but I don't use texstudio so don't know the details.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102272/texstudio-how-to-add-custom-highlighting-for-custom-environment

Comment: I changed the textpos.cwl file in ...\AppData\Roaming\texstudio\completion\autogenerated\ and added:

\begin{textblock*}#\env    
\end{textblock*}#\env

Now it's working and I don't have the issue mentioned of the red box. Thank you!